# AJAX Microgames

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, game-engine

If you're not familiar with the concept of a Microgame, check out this [video of WarioWare Twisted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxYIN0PBZU4).

I'm interested in setting up a site where users can play series of browser-based Microgames which are delivered to them by a server. Ideally this would allow me to crowdsource the games and have an open submission system. What sort of scheme could I use to make this work?

I'm thinking that one way to do it would be to have each game consist of:

- A javascript file that defines a MicroGame object that controls a rectangular portion of the screen, gets input and timing information from the main page, then calls back to the main page with a "Success" or "Failure" message.
- A folder of assets that must be downloaded before the game executes.

Is this possible to do, client-side within a browser? Where would be a good place to start figuring this out?

Comment: Isn't the word "ajax" soooo 200x?

Comment: I guess I'm not trendy!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of open issues here. The biggest problem is what language do they submit games in which you can execute safely on the players machines? That said, there are tools like this out there. You could look at the excellent [Play My Code](http://www.playmycode.com/) for inspiration.